# jQuery: Get tag inside element with class

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="yes">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <something>...</else>
    <p>foobar</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the p-tag to append a classname

```
$("div.wrapper", "#yes").addClass("newClassName");
```

But where to add the "p"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
$("div#yes > div.wrapper > p").addClass("newClassName");
```

[Here is a jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V4XHP/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".wrapper").find("p").addClass("newClassName");
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by the folowing code:

```
$("#yes div.wrapper p").addClass("newClassName");
```

This code gets any p-tag within any div with the class "wrapper" which is located in an element with the id "yes".

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#yes").find("p").addClass("newClassName");
```